# why mean not working in Reduce?

Tags: r

There are two examples of function `Reduce()` in Hadley Wickham's book *Advanced R*. Both work well.

```
Reduce(`+`, 1:3) # -> ((1 + 2) + 3)
Reduce(sum, 1:3) # -> sum(sum(1, 2), 3)
```

However, when using `mean` in `Reduce()`, it does not follow the same pattern. The outcome is always the first element of the list.

```
> Reduce(mean, 1:3)
[1] 1

> Reduce(mean, 4:2)
[1] 4
```

The two functions `sum()` and `mean()` are very similar. Why one works fine with `Reduce()`, but the other does not? How do I know a if a function behaves normally in `Reduce()` before it gives incorrect result?

Comment: Like @nrussel explained, `mean` is not a binary function. So, to get the `mean` of a vector of elements with `Reduce` you need to define a binary version, e.g. `Reduce(function(x, y) mean(c(x, y)), 1:3)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has to do with the fact that, unlike `sum` or `+`, `mean` expects a single argument (re: a vector of values), and as such cannot be applied in the manner that `Reduce` operates, namely:

> Reduce uses a binary function to successively combine the elements of
>   a given vector and a possibly given initial value.

Take note of the signature of `mean`:

```
mean(x, ...)
```

When you pass multiple values to it, the function will match `x` to the first value and ignore the rest. For example, when you call `Reduce(mean, 1:3)`, this is more or less what is going on:

```
mean(1, 2)
#[1] 1

mean(mean(1, 2), 3)
#[1] 1
```

Compare this with the behavior of `sum`, which accept a variable number of values:

```
sum(1, 2)
#[1] 3

sum(sum(1, 2), 3)
#[1] 6
```